# How to send a custom reject notification in Qmail (badmailfrom File)?

Tags: email, spam

i´m using QMail and i want to reject various emailadresses (domains).

I found the following way:

Block Email Senders in QMail: /var/qmail/control/badmailfrom

When i block a sender he will get the following reply:

```
553 sorry, your envelope sender is in my badmailfrom list (#5.7.1)
```

However i dont want to tell spammers that i added them to a block list. Rather than that they should get a message like:

```
550 No such user here (#5.7.1)
```

I think the message is hardcoded in QMail. But maybe one of you knows a good way to customize the block message.

Answer (score 0):

At least one patch set for qmail (the [spamcontrol patches](http://www.fehcom.de/qmail/spamcontrol/README_spamcontrol.html#Qmail-smtpd)) allows for customized error messages which you can set from the environment in your `tcpserver`,`runit`, or equivalent "run script" with `REPLY_BADMAILFROM` and a `control/smptreplies` control file.

I'm not sure it this has made its way into other "patches included" distributions like `netqmail` or if it can be applied separately. Drop-in replacements for `qmail-smptd` (*e.g.* [`qpstmpd`](http://smtpd.github.io/qpsmtpd/)) allow for this kind of customization as well.